# How to match Android Studio TODO comment patterns that include a colon in their regex

Tags: android, regex, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.1 .

I'm trying to create an Android Studio TODO pattern (Settings → Editor → TODO → Patterns) with regular expression that will match the word `bug` followed by `:` no matter where this combination written in the sentence.

The following sentences are ones that I want to match:

- `bug:` not working.
- `BUG:` whatever...
- this is a `BUG:` !

In contrast to the above, the following sentences are ones that I **don't** want to match:

- this is a bad bug.
- is it that buggy
- lots of bugs and no solution.
- :BUG doesn't work.

I currently have `\bbug\b.*` regular expression that works but he also works when `:` character is missing.

I've tried the following regular expressions without a success:

- `\bbug:\b.*`
- `\bbug\\:\b.*`

I would like to know how can I crate a regular expression pattern that consist of the word `bug` followed by `:` as a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put the colon on the outside of the pattern, like so: `\bbug\b:.*`

This grabs `bug:`, `BUG:`, but not `bug`, `BUG`, or `:BUG`.

Comment: Thank you very much, working just as expected, any further information why it is working?